# How to check specific yaml structure with groovy

Tags: groovy, yaml

In a groovy project i have to find a way to check YAML files
that have to be something like this in it's structure:

```
version: 1

path:'/somepath'

params:
    'param1': 'value1'
    'param2': 'value2'
    'param3': 'value3'



path:'/somepath/that/can/not/be/the/same/in/the/file'

params:
    'param1': 'value1'
    'param2': 'value2'
    'param3': 'value3'
```

rule 1: there can only be 1 line at the start with the version
rule 2: there can be 1 or more path params groups but only with a UNIQUE path value in the file never with the same path

i'm quite new in groovy much more in it's libraries and i want to find the best way to do this kind of validations

Comment: Something wrong with your yaml. Keys of the same level must be unique. So, you can't have two `path` items on the same level.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: @julian Have you tried converting this YAML to JSON? That way you will be able to get key-value pairs & perform validation as per rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to validate YAML as part of shared library on Jenkins, then you can use [readYaml](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/) method that will give you key-value pairs for performing validation:

```
     def datas = readYaml file: 'dir/my.yml'
     if(datas?.params){
      ...
     }
```